# Does anyone else think the filter system for questions needs some consideration?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, questions

Okay so I want to look at questions from the criteria - my favourite tags, new AND unanswered. This seems like it would be a regular request right why must I sift through all the other stuff when that could be done by some more elegant filter solutions on the site itself? Am I missing something simple where this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something similar by using `hasaccepted:no` *(for no accepted answer)* or `answers:0` *(for 0 answers)*

So you'd do a research like  :

```
([mytag1]or[mytag2])[mytag3] keyword phrase hasaccepted:no
```

Then sort the results using the "newest" tab in the Result Page.

[image: Newest tab]

For more information you can click the "Advanced Search Tips" link that appears in the [Search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search), just right to the search box.

[image: advance search]

Comment: and the query can be bookmarked

Comment: This is definately going in the right direction,thank-you, but wouldn't it be easier if you could change the preferential order its listed in by just clicking on a heading?

Comment: @AMAN77 Well the difference is that using `answers:0` doesn't change the order but changes the query. The order can be changed on the result page (pressing the 4 tabs relevance, votes, newest, active)

Comment: This is why I capitalised AND in my opening, so that it would be possible to do both or have more than one priority. Not very hard coding either I mean just pull out all the unanswered questions with the appropriate tags and list them in order of the youngest date ? Anyways yours is the most appropriate answer that helps achieve the goal here so ... its the big green tick for you my friend!

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is represented by a great big button at the top of every page:

[image: unanswered tab]

"Unanswered" here includes questions with no answers, and questions with no *up-voted* answers. You get a tag-based filter, a score filter, a date filter, and a filter that excludes even questions with <=0-scoring answers.

For more complicated filtering, use a search such as [the one Hugo describes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190556/does-anyone-else-think-the-filter-system-for-questions-needs-some-consideration/190557#190557).

Comment: Mine isnt tag based. Unless I choose to ignore every single thing that might not pertain to a question I cant answer.

Comment: Did you click on the [my tags](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags) sub-tab?

Comment: Yes but they can still be quite dated.

Answer (score 0):

The default queue shows questions for your tags with the newest questions first. It does not filter out questions with answers, but this is a good thing. Questions with answers often need *better* answers, or would benefit from your unique perspective and experience.

There is a tendancy to skip questions with answers, perhaps to avoid competition or because of an assumption that the first answer is the *right* one, but in my opinion, new questions with answers deserve just as much attention as new questions without answers.

Comment: There is absolutely a place for this but shouldnt we be able to choose those filters ourselves?